# Changing the font of a single math symbol?

Tags: math-mode, fonts

Currently using the standard math font and was hoping to modify the standard \omega symbol. How do I go about configuring this so that I can get the \omega symbol from a different font package, say {fouriernc}, or something. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Importing a single symbol from a different font](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386/5764)